# Unable to use the site search function

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to use the built-in search function from the site but I keep getting results from the main page. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


body = {'input':'ferris'} # <-- also have tried'query'

con = requests.post('http://www.collegedata.com/', data=body)

soup = BeautifulSoup(con.content, 'html.parser')
products = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'schoolCityCol'})

print(soup)
print (products)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code:

1. POST url is incorrect. You should correct this:

`con = session.post('http://www.collegedata.com/cs/search/college/college_search_tmpl.jhtml', data=body)`

2. Your POST data is incorrect too.

`body = {'method':'submit', 'collegeName':'ferris', 'searchType':'1'}`

You can use Developer tools in any browser (Chrome preferably) and check POST url and data on page Network.